# solving xA=b using scipy.linalg.solve_triangular

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to use scipy.linalg.solve_triangular() to solve a system of the form xA=b (rather than Ax=b). Is there an easy way to do this? I thought that I could maybe transpose everything before using the function but doesn't seem to be working.  Any help appreciated, am a beginner in this area!

Comment: "...but doesn't seem to be working."  Please show what you tried.  What didn't work?  Did you get an error, or just the wrong answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector x must be (1 x n); the matrix A must be (n x m); the vector b must be (1 x m).

If you take the transpose of both sides, you get:

```
(xA)^T = b^T
```

Rearranging the LHS:

```
(A^T)(x^T) = b^T
```

Now A^T is an (m x n) matrix; x is a (n x 1) vector; b is an (m x 1) vector.

If A is square and symmetric, then by definition A^T = A.  No work needed.

You can solve for `x^T = (A^T)^-1 (b^T)` using the usual techniques.

I would not recommend computing a matrix inverse.  If your matrix is square, you're better off using LU decomposition and forward-back substitution instead.  It's far more stable.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a simpler way! Could the trans parameter be used somehow?

Comment: my matrices are all nxn

Comment: Good - that makes it easier.

Comment: Yes, trans='T' can be used to indicate that a solution of A^T*x=b is to be computed.

Answer (score 0):

why would you like to use `solve_triangular`? Did you mean simple Least-Squares problem? - then you'll need being triangular both upper & lower matrix anyway:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular
from scipy.linalg import solve
from scipy.linalg import lstsq, lu

np.random.seed(0)

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100) # sample dataset for independent variables
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100) # sample dataset for dependent variables
X = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(y)), x))   # for intercept

p,l,u= lu(X.T@X)    # LU-factorization
theta= solve_triangular(u, solve_triangular(l, p.T@(X.T@y), lower= True, overwrite_b=False, check_finite=True))
print(theta)

theta= solve(X.T@X, X.T@y)
print(theta)

thetaLS= lstsq(X,y.T)[0]
print(thetaLS)

# intercept, beta
# [ 4.93699392e+01 -6.21893497e-03]
# [ 4.93699392e+01 -6.21893497e-03]
# [ 4.93699392e+01 -6.21893497e-03]
```

Or what was the reason you have chosen `solve_triangular` for what task?

P.S. Another scenario [here](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/solving-xa-b-using-scipy-linalg-solve-triangular#solving-xab-using-scipylinalgsolve_triangular):

```
# for symmetrical positive definite Hermitian matrix -
# you could simply utilize this equation:  Q = inv(chol(S)) * X 
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np
N = 3
M = 1000
X = np.random.randn(N, N)
y = np.random.randn(N, M)
S = np.dot(X, X.T)

cS = scipy.linalg.cholesky(S, lower=True)    # Cholesky-factorization
b1 = scipy.linalg.solve(cS, y)

icS = scipy.linalg.inv(cS)    # be careful: do not use manual inverse whenever possible - it is numerically unstable
b2 = np.dot(icS, y)

print(np.allclose(b1, b2))

##################################
# better - there is special class for such decomposition

from scipy.linalg import cho_factor, cho_solve

X = make_spd_matrix(n_dim=3, random_state=1)
y = np.random.randn(3, 1000)

c, low = cho_factor(X)
b = cho_solve((c, low), y)
print("b: ", b)
print(np.allclose(X @ b - y, np.zeros(3000).reshape(3,1000)))
```